Find all "a" tags in multiple divs with same class with BeautifulSoup
I want to find all "a" elemnts in multiple divs with same class.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
links = soup.find_all("div", class_="va-columns").find_all("a")

but this doesnt work and gives me an error.
Can someone help me? Im trying to find all links on the main content of a website.

What's the error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

soup.find_all("div") will return a list. So you could simply loop through that list and for each div, you do div.find_all('a'). This way, you could have a list of all a tags in all div tags you wanted to search for.
Here's the code.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
links = [div.find_all("a") for div in soup.find_all("div", class_="va-columns")]

See this if you didn't get the for loop inside the list. (it's called a list comprehension in Python)

find_all() returns a list, so you would have to loop over the elements, calling find() on each of them and collecting all the results.
Instead you can use soup.select(), which takes a CSS-style selector.
links = soup.select("div.va-columns a")

